# One-Time-Pad Decryption

Tags: decryption, one-time-pad

For homework, I have a ciphertext which is 582 chars long. The OTP used was reused over and over. The OTP is 50 chars long.

How exactly can I now get the key and the cleartext?

Comment: Are we to assume that each character of the key was XOR'ed with each character of the message?

Comment: I also tried to XOR two 50 chars long strings from the ciphertext and then cribdrag that but i don't get to where i want.

Comment: Knowing that it's a contrived situation designed to help you learn makes a huge difference in how we answer you.

Comment: Is what you have posted all of the info you have? I feel like there is a piece missing.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a one time pad, it's a Vigenère cipher.

You'd break this by organising into 50 character chunks so the aligned characters have been XOR'd with the same key character. You then perform a frequency analysis on this result to get the most likely key value. Repeat for all 50 characters.